# Why are my images not stuck together?

Tags: html, css

I have this simple HTML / CSS

```
<div class="image-group">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" />
  <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" />
</div>

.image-group img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QrKDj/)

Why are the images not stuck together? I inspect the elements using Chrome's Inspector and it shows me nothing in between the images, yet they are spaced out.

I can get them to stick together by applying negative margins, but according to me, they should be sticking together anyways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's space in your html code. Try below

```
<div class="image-group">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" /><img src="http://placehold.it/120x120" /><img src="http://placehold.it/80x80" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out this blog post about dealing with spaces with consecutive inline-block elements such as images.

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Thanks for that link. I ended up commenting out the empty spaces.